# Pass a mixin a list and a variable

Tags: sass, mixins

Is it possible to pass a list of parameters as well as another separate parameter.

Something like

```
@mixin cols($width...,$gutter) {
  .... 
}


@include cols((4,4,4),2%);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes we can do that.non list parameters should be before list/array parameters

check this snippet

```
@mixin box-shadow($color,$shadows...) {
  -moz-box-shadow: $shadows;
  -webkit-box-shadow: $shadows;
  box-shadow: $shadows;
  background:$color;
}

.shadows {
  @include box-shadow('red',0px 4px 5px #666, 2px 6px 10px #999);
}
```

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_arguments

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, that does work for your box-shadow mixin, but I need to send through the argument list with commas, as I am using a @for loop to apply the values

Comment: so you want me to make changes using for loop?

Comment: does it help you in any way...if so consider accepting answer